# C struct initialization with char array

Tags: c, struct, char

I have a C struct defined as follows:

```
struct Guest {
   int age;
   char name[20];
};
```

When I created a `Guest` variable and initialized it using the following:

```
int guest_age = 30;
char guest_name[20] = "Mike";
struct Guest mike = {guest_age, guest_name};
```

I got the error about the second parameter initialization which tells me that `guest_name` cannot be used to initialize member variable `char name[20]`.

I could do this to initialize all:

```
struct Guest mike = {guest_age, "Mike"};
```

But this is not I want. I want to initialize all fields by variables. How to do this in C?

Comment: You can't copy arrays. Use `std::string`.

Comment: I know I can use `std::string`. But what if I want to stick with C-style char arrays?

Comment: You said C or C++. Now you say C.

Comment: I should make it clear. I want to do it in C char array. Have edited my question. Is it possible?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`mike.name` is 20 bytes of reserved memory inside the struct. `guest_name` is a pointer to another memory location. By trying to assign `guest_name` to the struct's member you try something impossible.

If you have to copy data into the struct you have to use `memcpy` and friends. In this case you need to handle the `\0` terminator.

```
memcpy(mike.name, guest_name, 20);
mike.name[19] = 0; // ensure termination
```

If you have `\0` terminated strings you can also use `strcpy`, but since the `name`'s size is 20, I'd suggest `strncpy`.

```
strncpy(mike.name, guest_name, 19);
mike.name[19] = 0; // ensure termination
```

Comment: So this way, I can't initialize other members of this struct using the form `Guest mike = {...}`. I have to use `mike.age = ...,; mike.id=...; memcpy(mike.name, guest_name, 20);` if I have more fields.

Comment: If you don't know the string in advance (at compile time), yes.

Comment: The `memcpy()` solution is undefined behaviour if the size of `*guest_name` is less than 20.

Comment: @nielsen according to the question, the size is 20

Answer (score 6):

mike.name is a character array.  You can't copy arrays by just using the = operator.

Instead, you'll need to use `strncpy` or something similar to copy the data.

```
int guest_age = 30;
char guest_name[20] = "Mike";
struct Guest mike = { guest_age };
strncpy(mike.name, guest_name, sizeof(mike.name) - 1);
```

You've tagged this question as C++, so I'd like to point out that in that case you should almost always use `std::string` in preference to `char[]`.

Comment: Thanks. So it is impossible to use C struct initialization to initialize char array members in declaration of a struct, right?

Comment: You need to add null terminator when using `strncpy`, generally speaking.

Comment: In this example I initialized the `struct` with the bracket notation which zeroes everything past the specified member. There was a related off-by-one error in the strncpy call, however, as well as some typos I'm surprised nobody's harped on. ;)  thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can statically initialise this struct:

```
struct Guest {
   int age;
   char name[20];
};

Guest guest = { 30, {'M','i','k','e','\0'}};
```

Each element of the array must be set explictly and this cannot be done using c-strings. If the struct is defined with a char* name then we can do this:

```
struct Guest {
   int age;
   char* name;
};

Guest guest = { 30, "Mike"};
```

Answer (score -2):

You can statically allocate a struct with a fixed char[] array in C.  For example, gcc allows the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int num;
    char str[];
} test;

int main(void) {
    static test x={.num=sizeof("hello"),.str="hello"};

    printf("sizeof=%zu num=%d str=%s\n",sizeof(x),x.num,x.str);
    return 0;
}
```

And it does the right thing (though beware of the sizeof(x): it returns 4 on my machine; not the length of the total statically allocated memory).

This does not work for structs allocated from the stack, as you might suspect.

Comment: (1) I don't believe GCC is so broken as not to return 6 for `sizeof("hello")` — but maybe you're referring to `sizeof(x)`, in which case `4` is the correct answer. (2) This is called a flexible array member in a structure. (3) The initialization is a GCC extension, though you have to invoke `-pedantic` to get it to 'fess up: `initialization of a flexible array member [-Werror=pedantic]` at `static test x={.num=sizeof("hello"),.str="hello"};` — compiler options `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic xx37.c`.  I'm using GCC 6.1.0 on Mac OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler does this extension also extend the allocated space to allow the initializer to fit?

Comment: @M.M: I'm not sure, but I think so.  I don't read x86_64 assembler well, but the output of `size xx37.o` (where `xx37.c` contains a copy of the code in this answer) gives a data section of size 10, which corresponds to the size that `x` should be if it was allocated as a single unit (which is how a FAM must be handled).  So, I infer that GCC does the job correctly (not a big surprise given that it does it at all), but I'm willing to be shown that I'm wrong on this.

Comment: While it is true that this idiom is a gcc extension [1], I don't see anything forbidding it in ISO C99 [2].
[1] https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.5/gcc/Zero-Length.html
[2] ISO/IEC 9899 section 6.7.8 paragraphs 20, 22.  Paragraph 31 is also worth a glance if you want to brush up on [].