# structure initialization error: incompatible types when initializing

Tags: c, data-structures, compiler-errors, initialization

I'm having problems with initializing structures via functions in C, and I can't seem to find what's wrong here. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
struct Date
 {
     int nMonth;
     int nDay;
     int nYear;
 };

 struct Book
 {
     char szISBN[10];
     char szTitle[75];
     char szType[50];
     char szPublisher[75];
     int nPages;
     float fPrice;
     int nYearOfPub;
     int nStatus;
     char szHolder[50];
     struct Date dueDate;
 };
```

Later on, in one of my functions:

```
struct Book addNewBook(struct Book *pBooks, int nStock, struct tm *t)
 {
     char szISBN[10];
     char szTitle[75];
     char szType[50];
     char szPublisher[75];
     int nPages;
     float fPrice;
     int nYearOfPub;
     int nStatus;
     char szHolder[50];
     struct Date dueDate = {t->tm_mon+1, t->tm_mday, t->tm_year+1900};//we will set this to be the current day by default

     ...

     struct Book newBook = {*szISBN, *szTitle, *szType, *szPublisher, nPages, fPrice, nYearOfPub, nStatus, *szHolder, dueDate};
     return newBook;
 }
```

I keep getting this really simple looking error and can't seem to fix it.

```
error: incompatible types when initializing type 'char' using type 'struct Date'
```

Unless I have dyslexia, the data types at the top of the program when I create the Book structure match up just fine with where I initialize the new book in the method later on in the program. What am I missing here? What's going on?

**Edit**: Here was the solution I used, thanks to REACHUS for linking another question which helped me find a solution.

```
struct Book addNewBook(struct Book *pBooks, int nStock, struct tm *t)
 {
     ...
     struct Book newBook = {"", "", "", "", nPages, fPrice, nYearOfPub, nStatus, "", dueDate};
     strncpy(newBook.szISBN, szISBN, 10);
     strncpy(newBook.szTitle, szTitle, 75);
     strncpy(newBook.szType, szType, 50);
     strncpy(newBook.szPublisher, szPublisher, 75);
     strncpy(newBook.szHolder, szHolder, 50);
     return newBook;
 }
```

Comment: What is `struct tm`?

Comment: @REACHUS: struct tm is included in <time.h> and I am simply using it here to get the system date.

Answer (score 0):

`*szHolder` in the initializer is equivalent to `szHolder[0]`, so this is a `char`.

In contrast to that the `struct` field `char szHolder[50]` is an array. Arrays can't be initialized by an expression, they imperatively need a `{ .. something .. }` initializer. This is similar to the fact that arrays can't be assigned, either.

But, if that is really the diagnostic message that you are getting, it is more than cryptic.

Comment: So the same goes for char szISBN[10] and all the other strings I'm trying to intialize? And would you have any suggested solutions on how to properly intialize those char arrays then? If I leave it just as szHolder, instead of *szHolder, then I get a lot of warnings in the build log telling me "initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]"
Initially I just ignored the warnings because I didn't understand them and figured they were a side-effect of a bigger problem I was having (which is often the case for me).

Answer (score 0):

You could fill your `Book` `struct` the same way it is described in one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966979/c-struct-initialization-with-char-array).

Comment: Thanks, thats what I ended up doing. I put in "" for each char array in the initalizer, and then on the following lines I proceeded to use strncpy() to replace the "" with the correct value I wished to put in the struct fields.