# Why is this a constant char, rather then a normal?

Tags: c++, char

First of all, I'm pretty new to programming. The problem I am having is, that I can't overwrite this char, because the IDE tells me, it is a constant even though I didn't declare it as one. The second problem is, that it won't print out the user names (I marked those lines with a comment) the error message tells me that this has something to do with a constant char as well. EDIT: About the 2. problem, I just realized, that I used %d rather than  %c but once I changed that, it just made things worse

This is "PersonenDrinks.h":

```
struct Person {
    int Armbrust;
    int Leistung;
    int Kamikaze;
    int Fraktion;
    int Spiral;
    int Zyklop;
    int Glueklich;
    int Waesche;
    int Bildhauer;
    int Neuheit;
    int Matze;
    int Kaenguru;
    int Parfuem;
    int Tasche;
    int Montieren;
    char Name [25];
};
```

and this is the main code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include "PersonenDrinks.h"

int main()
{
    struct Person User1;
    struct Person User2;
    struct Person User3;
    struct Person User4;
    struct Person User5;
    struct Person User6;
    struct Person User7;
    struct Person User8;
    struct Person User9;
    struct Person User10;
    struct Person User11;
    struct Person User12;
    struct Person User13;
    struct Person User14;
    struct Person User15;
    struct Person User16;

    User1.Name= "Kevin";
    User2.Name = "Stephie";
    User3.Name = "Erich";
    User4.Name = "TomLaurin";
    User5.Name = 
    User6.Name =
    User7.Name =
    User8.Name =
    User9.Name =
    User10.Name =
    User11.Name =
    User12.Name = 
    User13.Name == NULL;
    User14.Name == NULL;
    User15.Name == NULL;
    User16.Name == NULL;


    for (; ; )
    {

        int Person;
        int Getraenk;
        char AddUser;

        printf_s("Add User? = y/n \n");
        scanf_s(" %c",&AddUser);
        if (AddUser == 'y')
        {
            system("cls");
            printf_s("Bitte geben sie ihren Vornamen ein: \n");
            if (User13.Name == NULL)
            {
                scanf_s(" %c", &User13.Name);
                if (User13.Name != NULL)
                {
                    if (User14.Name == NULL)
                    {
                        scanf_s(" %c", &User14.Name);
                        if (User14.Name != NULL)
                        {
                            if (User15.Name == NULL)
                            {
                                scanf_s(" %c", &User15.Name);
                                if (User15.Name != NULL)
                                {
                                    if (User16.Name == NULL)
                                        scanf_s(" %c", &User16.Name);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }





        }
        else
        {
            printf_s("Bist du sicher, dass du dich nicht vertippt hast? Hattest du villeicht schon ein paar Drinks zu viel?");
        }

        printf_s(User1.Name ,"%d = 1 \n");   //here is the 2. 
        printf_s(User2.Name ,"%d  = 2 \n"); //problem
        printf_s(User3.Name ,"%d = 3 \n"); //and here
        printf_s(User13.Name ,"%d = 13 \n"); //and here

        scanf_s("%d", &Person);

        switch (Person)
        {
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            std::cout << "Was darf's sein? \n";
            std::cout << "Armbrust  = 1 \n";
            std::cout << "Leistung  = 2 \n";
            std::cout << "Kamikaze  = 3 \n";
            std::cout << "Fraktion  = 4 \n";
            std::cout << "Spiral        = 5 \n";
            std::cout << "Zyklop        = 6 \n";
            std::cout << "Gluecklich    = 7 \n";
            std::cout << "Waesche       = 8 \n";
            std::cout << "Bildhauer = 9 \n";
            std::cout << "Neuheit       = 10 \n";
            std::cout << "Matze     = 11 \n";
            std::cout << "Kaenguru  = 12 \n";
            std::cout << "Parfuem       = 13 \n";
            std::cout << "Tasche        = 14 \n";
            std::cout << "Montieren = 15 \n";
            scanf_s("%d", &Getraenk);
            system("cls");
            switch (Getraenk)
            {
            case 1:
                User1.Armbrust++;
                std::cout << "Das ist deine " << User1.Armbrust << ". Armbrust \n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 2:
                User1.Leistung++;
                std::cout << "Das ist deine " << User1.Leistung << ". Leistung \n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 3:
                User1.Kamikaze++;
                std::cout << "Das ist deine " << User1.Kamikaze << ". Kamikaze \n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 4:
                User1.Fraktion++;
                std::cout << "Das ist deine " << User1.Fraktion << ". Fraktion \n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 5:
                User1.Spiral++;
                std::cout << "Das ist deine " << User1.Spiral << ". Spiral \n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 6:
                User1.Zyklop++;
                std::cout << "Das ist dein " << User1.Zyklop << ". Zyklop \n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 7:
                User1.Glueklich++;
                std::cout << "Das ist deine " << User1.Glueklich << ". Glueklich \n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 8:
                User1.Waesche++;
                std::cout << "Das ist deine " << User1.Waesche << ". Waesche \n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 9:
                User1.Bildhauer++;
                std::cout << "Das ist deine " << User1.Bildhauer << ". Bildhauer \n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 10:
                User1.Neuheit++;
                std::cout << "Das ist deine " << User1.Neuheit << ". Neuehieit \n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 11:
                User1.Matze++;
                std::cout << "Das ist deine " << User1.Matze << ". Matze \n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 12:
                User1.Kaenguru++;
                std::cout << "Das ist deine " << User1.Kaenguru << ". kaenguru \n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 13:
                User1.Parfuem++;
                std::cout << "Das ist deine " << User1.Parfuem << ". Parfuem \n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 14:
                User1.Tasche++;
                std::cout << "Das ist deine " << User1.Tasche << ". Tasche \n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 15:
                User1.Montieren++;
                std::cout << "Das ist deine " << User1.Montieren << ". Montieren \n";
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `strcpy` to copy your names into `User1.name` and others too. Before that zero the memory using `memset` or `bzero`.

Comment: Still tells me it is a constant and I can't change it

Comment: In order to help us understand your level of understanding, please explain what you expect this to do `User12.Name = 
    User13.Name == NULL;`. Especially the difference between `=` and `==` and when you think those have an effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C struct initialization with char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966979/c-struct-initialization-with-char-array)

Comment: @Yunnosch I would say, that it sets the Name of User12,13 to be empty. = means that the Variable is the value that's behind the = and == checks whether the variable has the same value as behind the ==

Comment: @OmG it is c++ compiler. His code is mix of C & C++. C rures do not apply here. It is compiled as C++ code

Comment: What do you think happens first, the check with `==` or the assignment with `=`? I.e. what do you think, which of these two alternatives is identical to the behaviour of your code? `User12.Name = 
    (User13.Name == NULL);` or `(User12.Name = 
    User13.Name) == NULL;` ?

Comment: Please, please use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Person User1;
strcpy(User1.Name, "Kevin");
printf("%s", User1.Name);
```

must work.

When you declare `char someString[50]` your `someString` is a pointer to a set of characters that compound your string, more precisely to the first char. So you can't just do `someString = "Kevin"`, you have to copy each char of "Kevin" to `someString`. `strcpy` is a function that do it for you.

I can always do something like:

```
User1.name[0] = 'K';
User1.name[1] = 'e';
User1.name[2] = 'v';
User1.name[3] = 'i';
User1.name[4] = 'n';
User1.name[5] = '\0'
```

Which is hard work. That can be done by `strcpy`. `'\0'` define the end of the string.

Comment: Please help fighting the misunderstanding that StackOverflow is a free code writing service, by augmenting your code-only answer with some explanation.

Comment: A string is not a simple type variable as int or float. See my edit.

Comment: *When you declare char someString[50] your someString is a pointer to a set of characters that compound your string* this is plain wrong.  An array is **NOT** a pointer.  An array can decay into a pointer in a lot of cases but it is not a pointer.  Please stop the spread of such misinformation.

Comment: Nobody said an array is a pointer and after declare the variable someString, it becomes of type char*, a pointer to some char. That is what matters for the problem and is the reason why you can't assign to it another array of chars like "Kevin", what you could do is assign it to another char pointer

Comment: "it becomes of type char*" -- that's the point of the previous comment: **it doesn't**. After `char some_string[50]` the type of `some_string` is "array of 50 `char`". If you don't believe that, compare `sizeof(some_string)` with `sizeof(char*)`. In most contexts, when you use the name of a `char` array its type **decays** into a pointer to the first element of the array. But its type is, nonetheless, "array of 50 `char`".

Comment: Do that with an array different of type char or without '\0' out of scope when it was declared and you will get sizeof pointer